# Picking a Random Background Color from a List and Applying it to a Dynamically Generated Button - Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, kirby

I'm building a personal website using Kirby CMS. I have a nav menu that automatically adds new buttons for any new pages I create for the website. I would like each button to have a background color that is randomly chosen from an array of colors every time you load the page.

I've been using the following code:

This is the snippet that loads the javascript and generates the buttons for navigation.

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title><?= $site->title()?></title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale1.0">
            <meta  charset="UTF-8">
            <?= css('/assets/css/menu.css')?>
            <?= js('assets/js/script.js')?>
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="blog_content_container">
            <img class="background_overlay" src="<?= url('assets/svg/background_overlay.svg') ?>">
            <header class="header">
                    <nav class="menu">
                            <img class="logo_header" src="<?= url('assets/svg/logo.svg') ?>">
                            <?php foreach ($site->children()->listed() as $childpage): ?>
                                    <button class="menu_item">
                                            <a href="<?= $childpage->url()?>" class="menu_text" >
                                                    <?= $childpage->title() ?>
                                            </a>
                                    </button>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                    </nav>
            </header>
```

This is the Javascript I have written that is supposed to pick colors from an array and apply it to the buttons.

```
window.onLoad = () => {
    var colors = ['#ffffff', '#ffbd4b', '#ff634b', '#4b9fff'];
    var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    document.getElementsById('menu_item').style.backgroundColor = random_color;
};
```

Finally, this is the CSS that I have written.

```
.menu {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu_item {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    margin: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.menu_text{
    font-family: 'nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Everything loads as expected without throwing errors, but no background colors apply to the buttons. I appreciate any help you can give, I'm a beginner so please be nice :)

Comment: `menu_item` is a `class` not an `id`. So you should use `querySelector('.menu_item')` instead of `getElementsById('menu_item')` -> If that solves your issue, please remove your question voluntarily as it is caused by a typo. PS: There is also no `getElementsById` in JS as an ID has to be unique. Therfore only a `getElementById` exsist

Comment: Hi thank you for the help, I've changed it to `document.querySelector('.menu_item').style.backgroundColor = random_color;` but still not functioning unfortunately. Again thank you.

Comment: I found another typo: `onLoad` instead of `onload`. If I change the typo in a script it works for me: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/VwQzvXK

Comment: For each iteration of the loop a button is generated as `<button class="menu_item"><a href="https://hire-avery.com/my-life" class="menu_text">Page Title</a></button>` I don't get any errors.

Comment: Oh i'll change that typo and try!

Comment: PS: Anchor inside a button is invalid (HTML Markup) aswell. Either you need a button (trigger for a script)  or an anchor (directing to another resource). If you need to combine both, you should add an `eventListener` or `onclick`-trigger to the anchor.

Comment: I tried changing the typo too but no dice :(

Comment: You can visit the page at https://hire-avery.com/ is that helps.

Comment: I've got it functioning now actually, but it only applies to the first button generated and not each button. So that's given me a new direction to go troubleshooting now, thank you!

Comment: thats because you need to loop over all the buttons as `querySelector` aswell as `getElementById` selects only the first element. You can use: `document.querySelectorAll('.menu_item').forEach(el => el.style.backgroundColor = random_color);` However this again will apply the same color to every button. Alternativly you have to move the randomizer inside the `forEach` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is way more complex then the few typos I will revert to an answer now instead of keeping an extented conversation within the comments.

First there are a few typos:

1. `getElementsById` does not exsist. Naturally an id has to be unique and as such can onyl exsist once. So it has to be `getElementById`
2. The above mentioned typo does not matetr in the first palce as it is a wrong call. The called element has a class with that name and not an id so `querySelector` should be chosen.
3. `onLoad` actually causes an error and has to be written `onload`
4. If you fix all those typos the script will actually work. However it will only apply to the first element with that class. To apply it to all Elements the `querySelectorAll` has to be used and be combined with `forEach`
5. That will lead us to the next issue that. The random color will be for all elements the same unless we move the randomizer within the `forEach` function:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  var colors = ['#ffffff', '#ffbd4b', '#ff634b', '#4b9fff'];
  document.querySelectorAll('.menu_item').forEach(
    el => el.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
};
```

```css
/* for visualisation purpose only */
div {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_item">1</div>
<div class="menu_item">2</div>
<div class="menu_item">3</div>
<div class="menu_item">4</div>
<div class="menu_item">5</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've fixed everything and now it's working. You helped me understand how it all functions better.

Comment: great to hear, I just noticed another issue you havign now. Within your array you have `#FFFFFF` as color. IF that is used as background color then your button will be unreadable as your font-color is white aswell. Either you need to change the font-color or remove/change the white background-color from the array.

Comment: I was able to do that one on my own! It will pick a nonwhite color for the text and border if the background is white.